# Unity 3D import new asset

Tags: unity-game-engine, sketchup

I have exported .skp file from sketchup to .fbx file. When I open the .fbx file in Unity 3D it doesnot have the same color property as it had when I open it in sketchup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on Unity's FBX importer to properly set material parameters. It will attempt to generate the proper materials for you on import and assign them, but not all exporters create this information correctly, which seems to be the case with sketchup.

[This thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/99965-How-to-Import-a-Sketchup-%28-skp%29-Model-into-Unity-%28with-Textures%29) is probably the solution that would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-texture the model in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problem with texture shared in Unity.
What you need to do is add some texture...
I have a tutorial just for that... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGIBLPIz4oM
Hope this will help...

Comment: You should explain the details from the linked video in your answer. This prevents the answer from becoming useless when the video gets lost.